# Refs not updating during interval (react JS)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

In my code, I have a function that simulates the typing action of a bot (think chatGPT), I want to add a button that will stop the typing midway and finish it instantly, I am using a useEffect to check for updates in a ref that is tied to a button, but the value never seems to update until the interval itself is finished. In fact, no variable in my entire component updates until the interval is finished running.

```
  const [currentText, setCurrentText] = useState("");
  const [currentlyTyping, setCurrentlyTyping] = useState(false);
  const stopTypingRef = useRef(false);
  const intervalIdRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('ref updated')
    if (stopTypingRef.current) {
      clearInterval(intervalIdRef.current);
      textFinish();
    }
  }, [stopTypingRef.current]);

  const chatImitate = (textToType, move) => {
    let currentIndex = 1;
    setCurrentText(textToType.split(" ")[0]);
    textToType1 = textToType;


    intervalIdRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      if (currentIndex < textToType.length && move !== "instant") {
    
        setCurrentlyTyping(true);

        // Split the text into an array of words
        let words = textToType.split(" ");

        // Add the current word to currentText

        setCurrentText(prevText => prevText + " " + words[currentIndex - 1]);

        // Increment currentIndex after adding the word
        currentIndex++;

        if (currentIndex === words.length) {
          // If all words are typed, clear the interval
          clearInterval(intervalIdRef.current);
          textFinish();
        }
  }, 130);

return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalIdRef.current);
    };
};
```

```
      <button
        className="down-arrow absolute bottom-[20vh] right-[6vw]"
        onClick={() => {
          stopTypingRef.current = true;
        }}
      >
        Stop typing
      </button>
```

The ref in this button does not seem to trigger the UseEffect nor does it update anywhere in my code except for when the interval has finished running:

I have tried every solution chatGPT seems to give me but none of them are working. I believe some use of async may fix this issue? I am quite new to react Javascript so any insight into this issue will be much appreciated.

Comment: effects don't run when you update a ref without causing a rerender

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the useEffect dependency array to trigger the effect when a specific value changes. However, since stopTypingRef.current is a mutable object (a ref), its changes won't be detected in the dependency array directly. Try this code:-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [currentText, setCurrentText] = useState("");
  const [currentlyTyping, setCurrentlyTyping] = useState(false);
  const [stopTyping, setStopTyping] = useState(false);
  const intervalIdRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("stopTyping updated");
    if (stopTyping) {
      clearInterval(intervalIdRef.current);
      textFinish();
    }
  }, [stopTyping]);

  const textFinish = () => {
    // Your logic to handle text finish
    setCurrentlyTyping(false);
  };

  const chatImitate = (textToType, move) => {
    let currentIndex = 1;
    setCurrentText(textToType.split(" ")[0]);

    intervalIdRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      if (currentIndex < textToType.length && move !== "instant" && !stopTyping) {
        setCurrentlyTyping(true);

        let words = textToType.split(" ");
        setCurrentText((prevText) => prevText + " " + words[currentIndex - 1]);
        currentIndex++;

        if (currentIndex === words.length) {
          clearInterval(intervalIdRef.current);
          textFinish();
        }
      }
    }, 130);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalIdRef.current);
    };
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        className="down-arrow absolute bottom-[20vh] right-[6vw]"
        onClick={() => {
          setStopTyping(true);
        }}
      >
        Stop typing
      </button>
      {/* Your other UI elements */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```